# Infinite Scroll Does Not Scroll Unless Paused at Bottom of Page on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Infinite Scroll on my WordPress site with the implementation(no masonry) bellow.

The issue I'm having only applies to Safari and not FireFox or Chrome.

The bahavior is that if I scroll down and keep for scrolling on Chrome, the next pages eventually appear on Chrome/FF, but if I try the same on Safari, it will pause and stop scrolling until I stop the scroll motion(mouse wheel or trackpad scroll).

I must pause at the end of each page in order for it to continue scrolling.

Would a fix be a way to tell infinite scroll to scroll to the next page before i get to the bottom or do I need to add a 'load more' button and remove automatic scrolling some how.

If so, How would I do that with this implementation of InfiniteScroll?

```
var infinite_scroll = {
        loading: {
            img: window.phpInfo.templateDirectoryUri + '/library/images/ajax-loader.gif',
            msgText: 'Loading the next set of posts...',
            finishedMsg: 'All content loaded.',
        },
        navSelector  : '#nav-below',
        nextSelector : '#nav-below .nav-previous a',
        itemSelector : '.entries',
        contentSelector:"#content",
        pruneRemoved: false
    };
    jQuery( infinite_scroll.contentSelector ).infinitescroll( infinite_scroll );
```